# mscorlib: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Invalid storage account Please make sure your credentials are correct

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

After deploying Azure Function App via Visual Studio `publish`; am getting the following error (on the azure portal).

```
azure Function Error: The listener for function was unable to start.
mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
Invalid storage account Please make sure your credentials are correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `publish` was using the wrong storage path; can examine/correct it in VS by `Publish/Manage Application Settings/AzureWebJobStorage`